# Download IMG file populated in a PHP file?

Tags: php, html

I need a simple script that will download a image file to the user's computer. However, it is populated in a PHP file like this: `mydomain.com/image.php?id=234234` so I can't use it in download scripts that do it like this: `downloadfile.php?filename=images/1321.jpg`.

What's my best option?

Thanks,
Coulton

Comment: How does your server know where to pull the image from with that id?

Comment: It pulls the image successfully. It searches a mysql database and gets it from a restricted folder location, so I can't link to the actual file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the download script to send out a real filename so it'll get saved as "1321.jpg" on the user's computer, and not "234234".

That's accomplished via the Content-disposition HTTP Header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="234234.jpg"
```

Comment: is right, you'll probably have to redirect the user to a new page using only this header to invoke the download.

Comment: What would be the user go to after downloading file? Right now I open it up via `_blank` and I would like to have the window close or something. What's the best way to do that? Thanks, Coulton.

Comment: They shouldn't go anywhere. Most browsers, when confronted with an "attachment" file, will stay on the same page that started the download.